# How to patch the now method of datetime while preserving other methods?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, mocking

It is the function I want to test

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, time
def my_func():
    result_date = datetime.combine(datetime.now(), time.min) + timedelta(days=look_forward)
    ...
```

It is my unit test code

```
@patch('batch.mymodule.datetime')
def test_retrieve_data(self, mock_datetime):

   mock_datetime.now = Mock(return_value=datetime.datetime.strptime('Feb 14 2015', '%b %d %Y'))

   my_func
```

I think it works as intended. However the `patch` also mocked the other method `combine`. I will get this exception from `my_func` later on

```
BadValueError: Expected datetime, got <MagicMock name='datetime.combine().__add__()' id='4494328976'>
```

I can fix it by adding this to the unit test:

```
mock_datetime.combine = datetime.datetime.combine
```

But it means I have to patch each individual method in `datetime` if it is used.

Is there any better, simpler alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define `datetime.datetime` subclass to use it as a mock object's class:

```
class MockDatetime(datetime.datetime):
    fake_now = None

    @classmethod
    def now(cls):
        return cls.fake_now


class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('mod.datetime', MockDatetime)
    def test_retrieve_data(self):
        MockDatetime.fake_now = datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 14)
        my_func()
```

DEMO: http://asciinema.org/a/63nrqzrysunyeq76xl72f943k

Answer (score 1):

This does not answer your question, but I just think it's worth mentioning another approach. For my project I used [freezegun](https://github.com/spulec/freezegun).

```
from freezegun import freeze_time
import datetime

class SomeTest(TestCase):

    @freeze_time("2015-08-10 00:00:00")
    def some_test_case(self):
        print(datetime.now())

  2015-08-10 00:00:00
```